# Is "disappear" stative or dynamic

Tags: verbs, semantics, stative-verbs

I believe that *disappear* (and *vanish*) are stative verbs because it seems that they do not have progressive aspect. I want to confirm it.

Comment: The point of your question is vanishing and disappearing before my eyes. Feels kind of dynamic to me.

Comment: I think *disappear* is similar to *become*. So it could be both stative and dynamic

Comment: (1) Progressive is not a tense. (2) It does seem that _disappear_ and _vanish_ can appear in the progressive construction. Revise your beliefs and all will be well.

Comment: What question are you really asking here,  merely whether anything can ever be said to *be disappearing*?